Shared libraries not found after upgrade to 24.04
Since upgrading to 24.04, I've been running into a lot of error messages pertaining to missing shared object files. Here are two related examples.
wget https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Gauguin#/media/File:Paul_Gauguin_1891.png

The response is
wget: error while loading shared libraries: libunistring.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Looking for libunistring:
apt search libunistring

The response is
apt: /snap/gnome-42-2204/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.32' not found (required by apt)
apt: /snap/gnome-42-2204/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.32' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0)
apt: /snap/gnome-42-2204/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.32' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)

Any advice?

Please try the commands sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade and sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^.

Thanks, doing that now. I'm running the Xubuntu desktop. Should I still use sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^?

Use sudo apt install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop^

I successfully ran the three commands overnight. I still have the symptoms described in my original post.

One of the error messages is get: error while loading shared libraries: libunistring.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. However, I have several copies of that file in various /snap/core20/ /snap/core22/ directories.

Archisman's solution was correct! I needed to close my bash session and start a new one, and the shell commands are running correctly. Thank you.
